# Importing pre-built content into the site

Tags: importing-exporting

There are frequent installs of Drupal 7 that I do. All of them are almost the same, except, some need to have additional content types and modules on top of the default setup.
I'd like to ask if there is a way to modularize the deployment to save time on manually creating content types and installing modules.

Example:

1. (Required) I download and install Drupal 7 (possibly Drupal 8 in the future) with minimal profile
2. (Optional) I import a "magic package" (prebuilt) that would import all the custom content types I made, menu items, views and extra modules into the site created in step 1.
3. (Optional) I import a second "magic package" (also prebuilt) that would give site more capabilities with additional modules, menu items, views and content types.

some of the imported stuff is linked to Drupal users via Entity Reference fields.

What is the best way to accomplish something like this?
Is there a module that can help me build these "Magic Packages"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating a feature could be what you need. Have a look at its project page. https://www.drupal.org/project/features

Comment: Can "Features" handle entity references and views?

Comment: Yea features is awesome!!! Nice one Niall

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking into drush make and .make files and custom installation profiles. You can set up a pretty solid base sites this way.

Comment: Install profile is nice. What about if I want to deploy a section of the site onto site that has been live and populated with content?